# Magento https not working in localhost

Tags: magento

I have changed my magneto localhost to https.My site is not working now.I want to go back to http.For that I have made changes in the table core_config_data web/secure/base_url to **"http"** ,web/secure/use_in_frontend,web/secure/use_in_adminhtml to **"1"** but still it is working

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It will not work on localhost. Because local server don't support the ssl. You must have ssl install on your server to run it using https. You will need to install openssl.

http://www.neilstuff.com/apache2-ssl-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

Change secure base url in `core_config_data` from https:// to http://.

Also, since you're talking localhost, I take it this is a dev machine. If it's running under Linux, it's pretty easy to create your own CA, add it to your browser cert store and create a self signed certificate for your web server. You'll have to add a virtual host entry for port 443 and the usual SSL specific entries in it. Makes Magento development go a lot easier.